# When I ran maven build no manifest.mf file is created

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have run `mvn package` but neither `manifest.mf` file not META-INF folder has been created in "C:\Users\villu\eclipse-workspace\cucumber\target\classes", even the build is successful.

Answer (score 1):

The manifest.md will be in the jar file inside META-INF, not in the target/classes directory